# I have just put oil in mycar & its about 13mm over the max line on the dip stick i havent driven my vehicle since i put it it is it o.k?

Tags: oil

My oil was low in my Mazda Atenza so I put oil in & it went over the max on the dip stick of 13mm I haven't driven since I put the oil in is it alright or do i need to siphon ??

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 6):

13mm additional depth of oil is quite a lot. If this were my car I would siphon out the excess. Too much oil in the crankcase can get whipped into foam and cause loss of oil pressure and engine damage.